# Ammend a R data.frame cell based on whether another cell within the row is contained in another object

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, lapply, sapply

I have a data.frame - UnknownSamples - with a column $Identity, and another column $ID.
I want to change the values of $Identity to "Parent" if the $ID in a particular cell is in a reference data.frame (but it can be a list) - ParentSamples.

This is my attempt:

```
lapply(UnknownSamples, function(x) if_else(UnknownSamples$ID[x] %in% ParentSamples$ID, UnknownSamples$Identity[x] <- "Parent", UnknownSamples$Identity[x] <- "Unknown" ))
```

`UnknownSamples` has multiple entries of most ID values, but `ParentSamples` only has one instance of each values. I do not know why this command is throwing an error however, since there shouldn't be a reason why a cell in `ParentSamples` cant be referenced twice. The error:

`Error: Assigned data`  `must be compatible with existing data. x Existing data has 1271 rows. x Assigned data has 2542 rows. ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.`

I am probably returning the incorrect thing in the function but I am not sure how to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> UnknownSamples$Identity <- if_else(UnknownSamples$ID %in% ParentSamples$ID, print("Parent"), print("Unknown"))

The solution is to have the `if_else` output what you want and then assigning it into the data.frame.